# Are NFC "writer" devices commercially available?

Tags: nfc

I'm looking into NFC for use with Android phones and the newest iPhones. What I'm envisioning is some kind of NFC "broadcast" device plugged in via USB cable to a computer, so that it always sends out the most up-to-date information to whatever NFC-enabled phone is within close proximity. So far I've been seeing a whole lot of NFC "tags," which I assume are rather stupid devices that are pre-programmed with essentially static content. I'm wondering if there are any USB NFC devices on the market that can be more dynamic. Do such products exist? What's the best search keyword to find such a device? (What I've been searching for thusfar hasn't been turning up a whole lot of results.)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for a hardware recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

"NFC "broadcast" device plugged in via USB cable to a computer, so that it always sends out the most up-to-date information to whatever NFC-enabled phone is within close proximity" is your requirement. As I see in market there are NFC Readers with USB plugin to computer. They are active NFC devices generating 13.56MHz and mostly used for payment purposes. However they are putting these devices to ticketing, Office ID applications. When you bring your NFC Phone within this reader's proximity, the reader will read your phone's data and shall send it to the computer as encrypted data and will be verified in your Computer. In this process, phone acts as passive device while reader is active device.

You can also control this reader using your corresponding Software in computer which you wish as dynamic writing.

I think this might help you http://www.acs.com.hk/en/products/3/acr122u-usb-nfc-reader/